# How does stand for "get V"?

Tags: slang, acronyms

> I remember we would dream about kids
>   Tryna get that V with that crib
>   Back when you used to be’s with that Crip

I can suppose it means a vehicle, but might it be something else?

This is from the lyrics to *[Sundress](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/asaprocky/sundress.html)* by the group A$AP Rocky.

Comment: I don't think this is an acronym, and I've added a new tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well the Urban Dictionary says V can mean car.

So,trying to get that V with that crib.

get here means: to obtain or to buy.

Trying to get a car to go along with an apartment, for him and the girlfriend.